# I have a problem with running a react native app using expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Sunny\fitnessApp\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\utils\downloadExpoGoAsync.js:78
bar.update(progress, total);
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'update')
at Object.onProgress (C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Sunny\fitnessApp\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\utils\downloadExpoGoAsync.js:78:25)
at onProgress (C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Sunny\fitnessApp\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\api\rest\wrapFetchWithProgress.js:52:61)
at PassThrough. (C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Sunny\fitnessApp\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\api\rest\wrapFetchWithProgress.js:44:21)
at PassThrough.emit (node:events:525:35)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
at node:internal/streams/transform:182:12
at PassThrough._transform (node:internal/streams/passthrough:46:3)
at Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:175:8)

Node.js v18.13.0

I want to run successfully on my virtual device android.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where exactly the issue is but its some expo internal issue you may try these commands to fix this.

1.Update the expo cli by running `npm install -g expo-cli@latest`.

2.Or.. you can run the command  `expo doctor`.

3.Delete the `node_modules` folder and run npm install again to reinstall all dependencies

4.Try running `expo start` and see if it reports any issues with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, open your terminal as administrator

1. npm install -g expo-cli
2. install dependencies
3. delete node_modules
4. npm run android (or the platform you want)

once you installed expo go on the device, the next time you can run it without admin permissions.

worked for me